# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch -- odd behavior when dynamically injecting container

Tags: css, ios, webkit, mobile-safari

I ran across a very strange behavior when injecting a container with the css attribute `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` dynamically and thought I'd ask for your thoughts/ideas.

Through AJAX I'm querying additional data and once processed add it to the DOM. However, when accessing the page the very first time (cleared cache) the container adds fine, but I cannot scroll! Refreshing the page through mobile safari reloads everything and suddenly the container scrolls...

There's no additional JS involved so I'm wondering why it would scroll the second time the page is loaded... Anyone have a take on why this could be?

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

probably because the page has not adjusted to the new content, you could just add `overflow-y: scroll` to the element which you will be adding content to, so that it always scrolls. Or add this when you add the new content.